# How to add Google Tag Manager data to React code

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, react-helmet

I have a React Application which includes several Static pages. I have added SEO data to these static pages using "Helmet" component. Now I got a "GA_MEASUREMENT_ID" from Google Analytics to use it inside Helmat tag. Google Analytics sent me three parts of data like this. The first piece is this that I added it inside "Helmet" tag:

```
<Helmet>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', '${GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}');
</script>
</Helmet>
```

But Google Analytics also sent me two other pieces of code that includes "Google Tag Manager(GTM)" data as following:

```
** Paste this code as high inside the <head> of every static page as possible.
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxxxxx');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

** Paste this code immediately after the opening <body> tag of every static page.
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-xxxxxxxx"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Now, my problem is that in my react code (which has not "head" and "body" tags ) where should I put these last two pieces of code?